# Adjusting toggle switch in smooth transuction and color change

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I'm trying to make the toggle button move in smooth transition just like IOS switch toggle.
And also I'm trying to change the border color of the #bounds to green when the toggle is on.

```css
#bounds {
    padding:2px;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    border: 4px solid #ececec;
    border-radius: 2em;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    color: transparent;
}

#bounds label {
    float:left;
    width:2.0em;
}

#bounds label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#bounds label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#bounds input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color: transparent;
}

#bounds label.on input:checked + span {
    background: #7FC6A6;
    color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

#bounds label.off input:checked + span {
    background: #ececec;
    color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="bounds">
    <label class="on"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>On</span></label>
    <label class="off"><input type="radio" name="toggle" checked><span>Off</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using any type of CSS pre-processor?

Comment: No, just this code

Comment: Fixed it, check out my code

Comment: 'On' is usually on the right for user interface, just my two cents

Comment: Awsome it works just as i wanted :)

Comment: @DigiNet Events, but you wanted to change border color as well which is not working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out part of it. You're using two separate items for the transition. Instead, use one. Put them under the same label. Also, add transitions to the span that's sliding. Make the buttons opacity 0 and make them take up the entire size of the label. When a button is checked, you set it to `display : none`. The other one will take it's place. Also, since they take up the entire size of the container, it doesn't matter where you click.

**UPDATE**
Fixed it :D

```css
#bounds {
  padding:2px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  border: 4px solid #ececec;
  border-radius: 2em;
  overflow:auto;
  float:left;
  color: transparent;
}

#bounds label {
  float:left;
  width: 4.0em;
  height: 2.0em;
}

#bounds label span {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  background : #7FC6A6;
  width: 2.25em;
  height:2em;
  border-radius : 20px;
  transition : 350ms all;
}

#bounds label input {
  position:absolute;
    width: 4.0em;
    height: 2.0em;
  opacity: 0;
}

#bounds label input.off:checked + span {
  background-color:#404040;
  color: transparent;
  margin-left : 1.75em;
}

#bounds label input.off:checked
{
  display : none;
}

#bounds label input.on:checked + span {
  background: #7FC6A6;
  color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  float: left;
  margin-left : 0;
}

#bounds label input.on:checked
{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<div id="bounds">
  <label>
    <input class="on" type="radio" name="toggle" >         
    <input class="off" type="radio" name="toggle" checked>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavsScript to toggle one label instead of two. Also, removed floating part and made transition:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bounds">
    <label class="off"><input type="radio" name="toggle" checked>             <span>Off</span></label>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#bounds").on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).find('label').hasClass('off')) {
    $(this).find('label').removeClass('off');
    $(this).find('label').addClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).find('label').removeClass('on');
    $(this).find('label').addClass('off');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }  
  return false;
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#bounds {
    padding:2px;    
    border: 4px solid #ececec;
    border-radius: 2em;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    color: transparent;
    width:4em;
    height: 24px;
}

#bounds.active {
  border-color: #7FC6A6;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#bounds label, #bounds span {
    width:2.0em;
}

#bounds label.off span {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#bounds label.on span {
transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#bounds label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#bounds label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#bounds input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color: transparent;
}

#bounds label.on input:checked + span {
    background: #7FC6A6;
    color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;

}

#bounds label.off input:checked + span {
    background: #ececec;
    color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6x4kath/30/)

Comment: As long as current post has tag JavaScript, so I did it with JS. It is simple jQuery click event which can be replaced with another library.

Answer (score 0):

Added a bounce effect, see if you like it

```css
#bounds {
  padding: 2px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  border: 4px solid #ececec;
  border-radius: 2em;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  color: transparent;
  height: 25px;
}

#bounds label {
  float: left;
  width: 2.0em;
}

#bounds label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: block;
  height: 19px;
}

#bounds label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

#bounds input:checked+span {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: transparent;
}

#bounds label.on input:checked+span {
  background: #7FC6A6;
  color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-animation: toggleOn 0.1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: toggleOn 0.1s;
}

#bounds label.off input:checked+span {
  background: #ececec;
  color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes toggleOn {
   0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0px, 1);
    background-color: #404055;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0px, 1px);
  }
}

@keyframes toggleOn {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0px, 1);
    background-color: #404055;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0px, 1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bounds">
  <label class="off"><input type="radio" name="toggle" checked><span></span></label>
  <label class="on"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span></span></label>

</div>
```